# What are Entity Value and Service classes means?

Tags: uml, entity, class-diagram, use-case

I googled and tried many online links to find out the Entity, values and service classes. But nothing found. 
Can someone explain with a good example that how to find out such classes from a class diagram?
take this [ClassDiagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqrqh.jpg) for instance.

Comment: The class diagram you reference is an arbitrary class diagram and does not seem to be related to your question in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities, values and services seem to refer to a [Domain Driven Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) context:

- an [entity](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html) is an object which has its own identity, and keeps its identity despite potential modifications of the values in its fields.
- a [value object](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) is an object which has not an own identity.  A value object is defined by the value of its fields.  Therefore it should in principle be immutable.
- A [service](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) is an operation that is not of the responsibility of an object (entity or value). THe DDD service is not to be confused with a service layer

In your diagram:

- all classes have their own ID, which suggest that they are all entities.  `User_vehicle` ssems to have a bad naming.  It should be called "Subscription".
- `User` and `Vehicle` seem to be aggregate root, with other entities depending on them.  `Maintenance` and `Schedule` seem to belong to the `Vehicle` aggregate.  It can be discussed whether `User_Vehicle` and `Reservation` would belong to the `User` aggregate or the Vehicle aggregate.
- There seem to be no apparent class for value object.  A value object would not have an ID that ensures it's identity.  However, one could argue that dates are value objects, even if not represented explicitely in the diagram.
- Maybe I'm too old, but I can recognize no evidence of a service here.  All the methods seem to be clearly of the responsibility of the object they belong to. A service could be "Create reservation" or "Start subscribtion":  in both cases these go beyond the responsibility of a single object:  it would always involve at least two entities.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to answer to your question since you do not precise the context.

Entities are classes whose instances are stored in DB, and after you get the three usual rules to store classes in db. see [ORM](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html)

If you are in JEE context, these classes are annotated by @Entity (almost).

A point, class diagram does not discover or find out classes, a class diagram helps to model your classes, not to find them.

Comment: Any link or anything that might help me to find my Value and Services Classes?

Comment: What do you mean by Valye and Services ?

Comment: I am not sure too, its been added in the requirement list, but its no where over the google that what is it.

Comment: Value i can not figure what it is, maybe reference values ? Like the list of countries, list of currencies, list of vehicules type and so on. Services could be classes which implement the business logic.

Comment: I@granier I think OP's referring to value objects and that he tries to understand some text written in a DDD context.